# Allow user to access only one computer in domain

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

I would like to set up a new domain user account in SBS2008.  I need that account to only be able to access a single computer, but access that single computer as a local administrator.

I am not an IT professional, sorry if this is really simple, I am learning!

Comment: Have you considered not joining that computer to your Domain? Keeping it as a standalone computer?

Comment: Can I access files remotely, ie \\computername\c$ with my admin account if I don't add to domain?

Comment: Yes, if you created a _local_ account on that computer with the same username and password as your domain admin account.  However, if you changed your domain account's password, you'd have to change the password on this machine as well.  VolrathTheFallen's solution is probably more suitable to your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I don't know about SBS2008 for sure, but I assume it will be similar to Windows Server 2008.)

In Active Directory users and computers, go into the users profile and look for the account tab. There should be a button "Log on to...". You can specify the computers the users is allowed to logon to.

[Screenshot](http://www.netometer.com/blog-pics/Configure-Active-Directory-UPN-Suffix.png)

Making the user a local admin must be specified on the machine itself, not the SBS.

Comment: Of the "Local Admin" thing could be configured in GPO... But either way, not on the SBS server.